# Google Cloud Armor/Kubernetes : BackendConfig ignored by ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I created a backend config as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-armor-backendconfig) and a cloud armor policy. Then I set the backend config on one of my service's port. It seems that the ingress ignores the BackendConfig.

I use the nginx ingress [controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx).

Comment: could you please add a little more details to the question. What I seem to gather is you created an object of kind: cloud.google.com/v1beta1, that had a "spec.securityPolicy.name", which you created using Compute Engine Method: securityPolicies.insert. However the second part of the question is a little fuzzy. Do you mean you created an ingress with apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1, kind: Ingress that uses glbc like the guide because that should work?

Comment: Hi! I found the solution to the problem, thus I'll wait until I am eligible to answer my own question properly. The problem had to do with reaching the max of load balancers due to trial and error. Then ingress could not use the proper global ip and get assigned a load balancer so that the rules would take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following the official documentation you might stumble with some issues that have to do with your quota.
You have a limit of 9 backend services by default. The gce configuration in comparison with the nginx-ingress recognises each service exposed through ingress as a backend service.
The best way to troubleshoot it is by issuing

```
kubectl describe ing
```

This will give you the logs needed.
The other issue that needs troubleshooting is when you don't have the correct cluster version which has supports for BackendConfig.